# PHP Regex - Getting querystring parameters from rewritten URL

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex string to extract parameters from different types of url, for example using `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`:

> string 1: "/news/page/4" or string 2: "/news/weekly/page/4"

I need to extract the string without last `/page/[ID]`, I mean only `/news/page` or `/news/weekly/`, etc. 
How can I do it with `preg_replace`?

Thank you.

Comment: What is your rewrite rule? The parameters are probably in $_GET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regexp solution:

```
echo preg_replace('/^([\w\W]*)\/page\/\d*/','$1','/news/weekly/page/4');
```

outputs:

```
/news/weekly
```

but you should use explode solution:

```
$parts = explode('/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
$url = $parts[0].'/'.$parts[1];
```

Comment: OK, thanks a lot :) I used regexp solution and works good, so how can I get with regex the [ID] of "/news/page/[ID]" or "/news/weekly/page/[ID]"? :)

Comment: preg_match('/\/page\/(\d+)/', '"/news/page/134"', $matches);

Answer (score 2):

You can use [explode()](http://php.net/explode) instead of regular expressions:

```
$delimiter = '/';
$parts     = explode($delimiter, $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
$whatINeed = $parts[0] . $delimiter . $parts[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use: [A-Za-z/]+
But it will be slower then just using substr. EDIT: not substr, but explode.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$foo = explode('/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
$resultant_url = $foo[0].'/'.$foo[1];
```